# How do you call a controller action with jQuery from your application.js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete plugin, and I want to customize this event:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
           $('.topic_field').val(ui.item.topic.name);
           return false;
```

Essentially, it triggers callbacks when an element from the dropdown list is selected. As of now, it only adds the selected element to the text field. I want both the field to be populated and for my application to send a POST request to the video update controller action, so that the user does not need to explicitly press the button. How can I do this?

UPDATE:

Here is the form in the show view of the video controller:

```
<%= form_for @video, :url => {:action => "update"}, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :topic_names, :class => "topic_field" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Topic" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var url = $('.edit_video').attr('action');
var val = ui.item.topic.name;
$.post(url, {data:val});
```

This is in my routes.rb:

```
resources :videos
resources :video_votes
resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :genres
resources :topics
resources :topicables
resource :session
```

Here's my update action:

```
def update
@video = current_user.videos.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @video.update_attributes(params[:video])
    format.html { redirect_to(@video) }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation on how to post the data from your select box to the relevant controller action.

I'm not familiar with the autocomplete plugin, but I presume it follows an onChange event on your select box. When the user has made a selection, you should execute the following (untested):

```
var url = $('myForm').attr('action');
var val = $('mySelectBox').val();
$.post(url, {data:val})
```

In your controller, you could access this using:

```
params[:data]
```

which would return the value of your select box. You can then use this as normal in your controller code.

Comment: would I just need to pass the `type` option and the `url` option as the url corresponding to the update action?

Comment: You don't need to pass the `type` option as it defaults to POST and the `url` option isn't explicitly needed as it picks up the string in the first argument.

Comment: In a restful controller, the update url will be in the form of `/resource_name/:id` i.e. `/posts/1`

Comment: ahh ok thanks, - how do I get the specific id of that resource? Do I just pass `:id`?

Comment: If the select box is in a form already, you can use jQuery to get the url from the form. If it is not in a form, I would insert the id in the view (probably in the select box) and get it using jQuery.

Comment: it is in a form... but I have no idea how to get the id of the resource from the form... I'd really appreciate an example.

Comment: `$(myForm).attr('action')` will give you the correct url - I've updated the answer

Comment: It is literally 'action'. That code will get the value of the action attribute in the form - in this case the url of the update action.

Comment: I got this error: `SStarted POST "/videos/455" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Apr 01 05:06:22 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/videos/455"):
`

Comment: Can you post up the view code for your form. and your jQuery functions.

Comment: yup, posted to the question details above

Comment: What is the source code output of the above? i.e. it should evaluate to `<form action='....`

Comment: Sorry, just seen your edited comment. I need to see the routes.rb file.

Comment: I suspect it's throwing an error because it is expecting a PUT request. Try amending the code to `$.ajax({type:"PUT",url:url,data:{data:val}})`

Comment: hmm, that doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't seem to add the tag... and I guess it's because i don't handle `params[:data]` at the moment, and I'm not sure how to handle this because normally i just use `params[:video]` since the tags are inside that hash... how would I incorporate this new hash? I'll post my update method above

Comment: Try the following: `$.ajax({type:"PUT",url:url,data:{video:{attr_name:val}})` where `attr_name` should be replaced by the attribute on your video model that you wish to update.

Comment: ok we're getting close... now it works (the tag is added) but it only appears after I refresh the page. the AJAX request that worked before is no longer being executed... just a normal HTTP request... how can I resolve this? Notice that I do have format.js in my `update` action...

Comment: Don't worry about it... someone else figured it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521217/why-is-an-ajax-request-not-being-triggered-here  thanks for all your help!

Comment: if you have time, maybe check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522023/loading-a-template-via-ajax-error

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery ajax function to fetch the data from your action url ("/topics/list") or something

```
$.post('video/update', 
  data: {yourdata},
  function(data) {
    //callback function
  }
);
```

in your video#update be sure to return something for your js request:

```
def update
   blah
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js { return somethinghere }
   end
end
```

Comment: I've typically had trouble with that function. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the POST occurs? Do you just want to update the database; redirect the user etc.

Comment: I want to update the database, yes. I want to do the exact same action as if the button of the form were clicked.

Comment: edited my answer. if you could try that i can help as long as you can post some more of your trials/code

Comment: hey, I've updated the question details with a lot more of my code