# Why is an ajax request not being triggered here?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have an autocomplete field where a user can select an existing or create a new tag. If a user creates a new tag, he presses the form button, and it sends a POST request to the update action in the videos controller which processes the request as AJAX, and the tag gets displayed above the field.

Now, the problem is when a user selects a tag from the suggestion list. By default, the jQuery UI autocomplete plugin appends the selected element inside the field, and then the user has to press the form button. However, I want to save the user some effort by automatically adding the tag right when it's picked from the suggested list. Therefore, I have this code in my application.js file:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
           var url = $('.edit_video').attr('action');
           var val = ui.item.topic.name;
           $.ajax({type:"PUT", url:url, data:{video:{topic_names:val}}});
           return false;
        }
```

That successfully sends a PUT request to the update action when an element is selected from the list. However, the request is NOT processed as AJAX. The tag is successfully added, but only after a page refresh. I want the request to be processed as AJAX. How can I do this?

I'm guessing that the problem has to do with the fact that when you press the form button, the `:remote => true` option tells rails to look for `format.js` (which I have in my update action), but when the button is not pressed, and an element is selected from the list, Rails does not know to look for JS. How do I let it know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that by something not being processed as AJAX that you mean that it's not rendering the `view.js.erb` file, but rather the `view.html.erb` file instead. You can fix this by forcing the format of the URL in your JS like this:

```
var url = $('.edit_video').attr('action') + ".js";
```

That would then send it to the right format for your action.

Answer (score 1):

Using dataType: 'script' in your Ajax request should help.

```
.
.
$.ajax({type:"PUT", url:url, dataType: 'script', data:{video:{topic_names:val}}});
.
```

This will add the correct headers to have rails recognize the correct answer format.

Answer (score 0):

'protect_from_forgery' might be stopping you from the post. You may check it with Firebug (with Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

I'd check to see if anything else is binded to $('.edit_video') in firefox.  You might be submitting the form.

Also JS could be disabled on the browser so it will degrade to non-ajax.

Finally check that you have the jQuery and <%= csrf_meta_tag %> in the layout file.  Good luck.