# Loading a template via Ajax - Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form that I want to load via AJAX into the video show view:

```
<%= form_for @video, :url => {:action => "update"}, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :topic_names, :class => "topic_field" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Topic" %>
<% end %>
```

I have this link in the video show view that when clicked, I want it to render the form:

```
<%= link_to "Add Topics", new_topicable_path(@topicable, :format => :js), :remote => true, :id => 'edit_topics_link' %>
```

I put the form in topicables/new.html.erb and I have topicables/new.js.erb file which has:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'topicables/new.html.erb') %>").insertAfter('.topic_holder');
$('#edit_topics_link').hide();
```

Now when I click the link, I get an error in my logs. This is what my logs show:

```
Started GET "/topicables/new.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Apr 02 03:58:52 -0700 2011
Processing by TopicablesController#new as JS
Rendered topicables/new.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered topicables/new.js.erb (2.6ms)
Completed   in 15ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= form_for @video, :url => {:action => "update"}, :remote => true do |f| %>
    2:   <div class="field">
    3:   <%= f.text_field :topic_names, :class => "topic_field" %>
    4:   </div>
  app/views/topicables/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_topicables_new_html_erb___1876131309_2172772700_0'
  app/views/topicables/new.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_topicables_new_js_erb__1367015167_2172792200_0'

Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (92.5ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (98.9ms)
```

What's going on? How can I fix this error to make the AJAX rendering of the form work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically telling you that `@video` is not defined. If that's the case you can either define it in your new method or use `:video` which creates a new instance variable rather than looking for one in the page context. Then you can handle the find and update in the update method.

Edit: jQuery load method

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $("#target").load("/topicables/new #new_topicable");
});
```

Comment: could you please expand or provide examples?

Comment: also, I'm unsure why this is happening... `@video` is defined in the video show view... unless it's the fact that it's not defined in `topicables/new.html.erb`?

Comment: It could also be `render :file=>` does not load the file in the context of that action. Why didn't you want to use `render :action=>'new'`?

Comment: because I dont have a new method in the topicables controller

Comment: before I moved the form out of the video show view, everything worked fine, so I'm unsure why it's all of a sudden undefined, even though im rendering it into the same view...

Comment: If it's loaded dynamically, then it's not being loaded in the context of the view you are rendering it to. I'd suggest creating a `new` method in topicables and initializing the model in there.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but then It says: `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"topicables", :action=>"update"})` (which makes sense because it's not there). So I copy and pasted the videos update method to topicables but I still get the same error..

Comment: Of course it wouldnt. That's a routing error. You need to add `resources :topicables` your routes.rb to fix that.

Comment: yes, I already have `resources :topicables` in my routes.rb. What could be causing the error?

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: it's ok. If you can think of an alternative way of doing the same thing, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: I can think of a pure jQuery way of doing it, which doesn't render the form in a js file before loading it, as you do here, so it may reduce the complexity. If you can see the form at `/topicables/new` then this should work. Check out my edit.